# How to run rake task multiple times in same file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have written multiple test cases in a file, and i want to run rake task in every test individually. 
When i run the test case with this command:

```
ruby -I test test/integration/my_test_file.rb
```

Then rake task runs only once. And many of my tests are failing. 
But if i run all failing test individually with this command

```
ruby -I test test/integration/my_test_file.rb -n test_name
```

Then all tests are passing.

**The problem is rake task is running only once in first case. 
But for individual test Rake task runs every time for each test case**.

here is how i setup rake task in my test file

```
require "rake"
MyAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

and in every test case i have this:

```
Rake::Task['tasks:my_task_name'].invoke
```

So how can i solve my problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok i got the answer.

here is how you can call `Rake::Task['tasks:task_name']` again within same scope, whether you want to run rake task in your controller file or in test file.

Whenever `Rake::Task['tasks:my_task_name'].invoke` execute then it sets a flag **@already_invoked**, which means that you cannot invoke that task again within same file. 
So you can do this

```
Rake::Task['tasks:my_task_name'].invoke

Rake::Task['tasks:send_overdue_reminders'].reenable
```

Here `Rake::Task['tasks:send_overdue_reminders'].reenable` flips the state of **@already_invoked** and you can call the rake task multiple times in same file

Answer (score 6):

I know is late but I think you don't need to `invoke` and `reenable` a task.

From what I understood you just need to `execute` them like:

```
Rake::Task['tasks:my_task_name'].execute
```